# Bill details by asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, product

Hi guys i just now started to learn asp.net.
Now i am trying to develop a billing software with sql database. I like to know how to calculate total and grand total of product in grid view format.

And also like to know multiply the prduct quantity with its prize.

Help just to add some codes in my project

Answer (score 0):

if you mean SQL statement, maybe could be like this:

To calculate the subtotal of each product sold

```
select product.name [item], 
       product.price [price], 
       order.quantity [quantity], 
       product.price*order.quantity [subtotal]
from product p, order o
where o.ProductId = p.ProductId
and o.OrderId = @orderId
```

To calculate the total price of each order could be like this:

```
select o.orderId, sum(product.price*order.quantity)
from order o, product p
group by order.OrderId
and o.ProductId=p.ProductId
```

the results of this querys can be sent to a grid like this:

```
myGrid.DataSource= myDataSet;  //dataset that returned the results
```